# Extract pull requests from Github API from specific date

Tags: github, github-api

I need a github API pull request URL that extracts pulls from a specific date period. I could extract complete data but i only need filtered data based on updated_at field (tried filtering with updated_at and updated with no avail)

tried below url without luck:
[https://api.github.com/repos/Alation/dw-dbt-alation/pulls?state=open&page=1&per_page=100&update>=2023-08-01](https://api.github.com/repos/Alation/dw-dbt-alation/pulls?state=open&page=1&per_page=100&update%3E=2023-08-01)